# Service Fabric: Use Refresh Mode for Faster Debugging

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2015, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

The Service Fabric Team announced in their [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-service-fabric-5-5-and-sdk-2-5/) that Service Fabric now supports *Refresh Mode* in Preview when debugging on a 1 Node cluster in Visual Studio 2015.

I've just installed the new Service Fabric SDK from the Web Platform Installer and have a .Net Core Web Application Service I'd like to try this out with.

Is there anything else I need to do to configure the Service/Application for Refresh Mode? I haven't noticed any new controls as such in Visual Studio. I can only hit *Debug* as normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [announce](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-service-fabric-5-5-and-sdk-2-5/) states about Refresh application debug mode in Visual Studio 2015 as follows:

> In conjunction with ASP.NET Core integration support, we’ve added a new **application debug mode** to the Service Fabric Application project. Refresh Mode allows you to quickly iterate between writing code and debugging and supports edit and refresh for ASP.NET Core services, so you can now develop ASP.NET Core services in Service Fabric the same way you would outside of Service Fabric.

Though LoekD has pointed it out, I also tried to install Azure Service Fabric 5.5 and SDK 2.5, you could find the **Refresh Application (Preview)** as follows:

[image]

Comment: For VS2017 - you will have to install the preview version of V2017 for now. The updated tooling will be in the next VS2017 update: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Answer (score 2):

It's a new option in the Application Debug Mode values, in the properties of your SF Application project.

(from the detailed release notes document)